# Highcharts labels cut off

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My highcharts labels are cut off. How can I fix this? Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels maybe?

Comment: increase the height of the chart's container (or make the labels smaller)

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to fix it by increasing the [marginBottom](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.marginBottom) of the chart, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421748/how-do-you-increase-the-height-of-the-x-axis-labels-area-on-a-highchart-js-chart).

Comment: could this be made dynamic however? What if you don't know the max length of your label value? any way to iterate and change the output?

Comment: I would also like to know if this margins and height could be made dynamic?

Comment: I do not know of a way to do this but haven't worked with Highcharts in a long while. I guess you could always draw a new chart but would think the difficulty is in knowing the needed margins and dimensions for the dynamic input. If you can calculate that before rendering the chart then you could definitely pass it but if not I think truncated labels or huge margins could be a compromise.