# Highcharts label text is not properly rendered

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, highcharts, text-styling

I am using highcharts in angular project, whenever labels are loading at the bottom text is not properly rendered, Please refer the image to find the exact issue (100.00%) please see braces.

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your code on some online editor?

Comment: its cropped, just add padding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536082/highcharts-labels-cut-off